# Python persist changes into function's parameter without return (leetcode: "Do not return anything, modify root in-place instead")

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree

when I solve [this problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/flatten-binary-tree-to-linked-list/) I have to deal with their requirement "Do not return anything, modify root in-place instead".
In my approach of solving this problem it seems that their checker won t see any change made on "root" after calling the function "flatten(self, root: TreeNode)" . I tried to print the new binary tree before exiting the function and it seems to be correct.
[image]
 The problem is that, unlike c++ where a simple "&" stores the changes into the parameter, python seems to not persist the changes so how can I satisfy "Do not return anything" ?
Please help me, I have to train a lot in python for a interview and I have no clue how to solve this issue .

---

[image: https://leetcode.com/problems/flatten-binary-tree-to-linked-list/]

```
# Definition for a binary tree node.
# class TreeNode:
#     def __init__(self, x):
#         self.val = x
#         self.left = None
#         self.right = None

class Solution:

    def flatten(self, root: TreeNode) -> None:
        """
        Do not return anything, modify root in-place instead.
        """

        # get tree in preorder traverse
        preordered = []
        def preorder(root):
            if root is not None:
                preordered.append(root.val)
                preorder(root.left)
                preorder(root.right)
        preorder(root) # for [1,2,5,3,4,null,6] creted preordered list as [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] so it s ok


        # construct a new tree with only right childs, from preordered list 
        root = TreeNode(preordered[0])
        next_root = root
        for i in range(1, len(preordered)):
            new = TreeNode(preordered[i])
            next_root.right= new
            next_root = new
        # it seems that root won t take change on checker and stays like how it was called
```

Comment: You'll have to alter the object you receive as `root`. Reassigning the `root` variable will not help you.

Comment: And what exactly "alter" does it mean ? Can you show me an example of adding to the root parameter a new node and making the program save the changes into the root  without return ?

Comment: You can alter the attributes of the object, its `val` etc.

Comment: So this mean that I am only able to change the previous tree, not to resign the root or to create another one and assign root to it

Answer (score 1):

> So this mean that I am only able to change the previous tree, not to
>   resign the root or to create another one and assign root to it
>   [sic]

That last clause is the critical understanding.  You must use the class methods to work through the original `root` object and alter the underlying structure.  Within your method, `root` is a local variable.  You can use that reference to affect the original.  Your late statement

```
    root = TreeNode(preordered[0])
```

severs the link utterly: you create a new object and use that to replace your only reference to the original.

Instead, restrict yourself to operations that work on the attributes of `root`, such as

```
root.right = <expr>
```

You can reassign to that, but not to the original root, as that's the calling program's only communication with your method.